# SQL Server 2008 memory bottlenecks

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am interested in query that I can run against SQL Server 2008 that would tell the memory usage of the current processes (and users running them) executing. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You have the full version of SQL Server? if yes you could use the Profiler.

Comment: Have a look at the excellent [sp_WhoIsActive](http://sqlblog.com/files/folders/beta/entry42453.aspx) by Adam Mechanic

Comment: ADmins this belongs on http://dba.stackexchange.com/ and we need to add http://dba.stackexchange.com/ to the list of places to move a topic to when you think it is out of place on this site.

Answer (score 4):

> tell the memory usage of the current processes

This is too generic and cannot be answered. Almost all the memory in SQL is shared between 'processes' (queries) and cannot be attributed to an individual one. The only significant memory consumption that can be clearly attributed to a query is the memory grant and that is exposed in [`sys.dm_exec_query_memory_grants`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365393%28v=sql.110%29.aspx). I recommend you read also about [Buffer Management](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337525.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests  
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle)
```

Or you may run:

```
sp_who
```

to see all users and processes

But, as Ezi stated, you can just use the SQL Server Profiler tool and run a trace.